# When appending a for loop's output in python why do I get the columns names with every apend?

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, append

So I am running a for loop as code example:

```
df=[]
for i in pd:
  final=......
  df.append(final)
```

I get he following output for df

```
A B C
1 2 3
A B C
4 5 6
```

and so on how do I make the append only append the values becauset his for is running for around 1000 times and 1000 times the df results are as the above

could anyone help

Thank you

Comment: What the `final` supposed to be? A `list` of column values?

Comment: Final is supposed to be a dataframe

Comment: Are you working on `pandas.DataFrame`? Do `pandas.concat(df)` after the for loop is done to make it a single dataframe.

Comment: What @Chris said worked perfectly so if you want to add it as an answer I will accept it Thanks man

Comment: @xxMrPHDxx I would but you see final is just a function I created that be something like `final=fun(X,Y)` and the function is long arround 300 lines